# How to coalesce a custom type in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce

I have this custom Postgres field:

```
execute("CREATE TYPE public.money_with_currency AS (currency_code char(3), amount numeric);")
```

How can I coalesce a null in this field to a default of "USD', 0?

Here's what I tried:

```
SUM(COALESCE(promotional_wallet_transactions.amount, ('USD', 0))) AS promotional_wallet_sums 

also tried:

SUM(COALESCE(promotional_wallet_transactions.amount, money_with_currency('USD', 0))) AS promotional_wallet_sums
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt with the record in parentheses is almost correct – you are only missing a type cast:

```sql
CREATE TYPE public.money_with_currency AS (currency_code char(3), amount numeric);
CREATE TYPE

SELECT COALESCE(null,('USD',0)::money_with_currency);
┌──────────┐
│ coalesce │
├──────────┤
│ (USD,0)  │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you new sql learned today :D